# two dimensional array

Tags: array

how can i store serial port available test to a two dimensional array. strings are separated with Z and end of text with #
pls help if anyone alrdy a solution

i am posting my program here

```
  String readstr;
  String finalstr;
  char *messages[][20] = { "" };
  int i, k = 0, lp;
  char chArray[] = "hai";
  String str(chArray);

  void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("System ready........"); // so I can keep track of what is loaded    
  }

  void loop()
  {
      int flag = 0;
      while (Serial.available() > 0)
      {    
          char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
          if (c == '#')
          {
              finalstr = readstr;
              readstr = "";
              flag = 1;
          }                 // I am getting data here on # 
          else    // and is available with finalstr
          {    
              readstr += c;     //makes the string readstr
          }
      }

      if (flag == 1)    // once data is available and terminated with #
      {
          int j = 0, l = 0;
          flag = 0;
          //Serial.print(finalstr.length());
          for (i = 0; i < finalstr.length(); i++)     //want to split in to strings 
          {
              //Serial.println(finalstr.length());
              // Serial.println(i);
              if ((finalstr[i] != 'Z'))          // if any char is Z, then split
              {
                  // Serial.println(finalstr[3]);
                  messages[j][l] = finalstr[i];          // rearanging in to String messages 
                  chArray[j] = finalstr[i];
                  messages[j][l] = '\0';
                  Serial.println(messages[j][i]);    // here it is not working
                  l++;
                  // Serial.println(j);
              }
              else
              {
                  l = 0;
                  j++;
                  String str(chArray);
                  // strncpy(messages[k],chArray,str.length());   // this is not working need help
                  //  Serial.println(messages[0]);
                  //delay(2000);
                  Serial.println(k);
                  k++;
                  //Serial.println(str);
              }

          }
          for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
          {
              Serial.println(messages[i]);    // I am getting here garbage value 
          }
          k = 0;
          j = 0;
          l = 0;
      }
  }
```

Comment: is this a school assignment? ........... what is the problem?  ....... do you get errors? ..... please use the edit button to add information to your post

Comment: Hi sir,  thinks for your reply. 
I want to split serially available text data to number of strings based on the separator character Z and end of data #
pls advice me to save the character data parsed to string array